# How do you delete columns in a for loop using openpyxl. I created a for loop using openpyxl that gets the column #

Tags: python, openpyxl

How do you delete columns in a `for loop` using openpyxl.
I created a `for loop` using openpyxl that gets the column #

Here's the code:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

badHeaders = ['data1','data2', 'data3']

for item in badHeaders:
    
    emptyColumns = []
    colNames = {} # current column numbers should be updated on every loop
    current  = 0
    for COL in ws1.iter_cols(1, ws1.max_column):
        colNames[COL[0].value] = current
        current += 1
       
    for colName, colNumber in colNames.items():
        #print(colName, colNumber)
        if colName == item:
            print(colName, colNumber)
            ws1.delete_cols(colNumber)
            wb1.close()
    
        else:
            pass

wb1.save(path2)
            
print('done')
```

The `for loop` keeps deleting the wrong column.

Comment: How can I make sure that only the proper column is getting deleted?

Comment: Colllect the column names and delete from the right